# Iterate component props in JSON format in vuejs

Tags: javascript, json, rest, api, vue.js

Can somebody help me?
I have a app tha use vuejs to create a SPA, in this app I get some data from API, follow the example:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    currentView: 'dash',
    devices: []
  }),
  created: function() {
    this.$http.get(API+'/devices')
      .then(result => {
      if (result.status == 200) {
        devices = result.data;
      }
    })
  },
});
```

This data was loading to data.devices and I used it to iterate in template, this is the problem, this is my template:

```
Vue.component('list-devices',{
  template:`
    <div v-for="device in devices">
      {{ device.description }}
    </div>
  `,
  props: ['devices'],
  created: function() {
    console.log(devices);
  }
});
```

When the function created print devices in template, it print the array(I used JSON.stringify to print it):

```
[
  {"user_id":33,"description":"MA002","created_at":"2017-1015 13:35:03","updated_at":"2017-1126 20:15:41","switch_on":0,"on_line":0,"id":2},
  {"user_id":33,"description":"MA003","created_at":"2017-1014 10:18:22","updated_at":"2017-1126 20:15:42","switch_on":0,"on_line":0,"id":670},
  {"user_id":1,"description":"SALA02","created_at":"2017-1125 12:07:05","updated_at":"2017-1125 12:07:05","switch_on":0,"on_line":0,"id":6672}
]
```

But nothing happen, and the data dosen’t be displayed.
Thank you a lot.

Comment: `this.devices = result.data`.

Comment: Thanks man, you are right. It works!

Answer (score 0):

I made some adjustments, things like remove from main instance of vue data.devices, put only in component. But basically the tip from @Bert solve the issue. (Thank you again)

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    currentView: 'dash'
  }
});

Vue.component('list-devices',{
  template:`
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Device</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Action</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr v-for="device in devices" :key="device.id">
            <td> {{ device.description }} </td>
            <td> {{ device.on_line }} </td>
            <td>  {{ device.switch_on }} </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
  `,
  data: function(){
    return {
      devices: '',
    };
  },
  created: function() {
    this.$http.get(API+'/devices')
    .then(result => {
      if (result.status == 200) {
        this.devices = result.data.devices;
      }
      console.log(devices);
    })
  }
});
```